# Calling Linux Socket and Epoll functions in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linux, sockets, interop

I'm making a custom framework for my special development needs, which includes very high performance socket management.

To achieve this on **Linux**, I need to call numerous functions from `<sys/socket.h>` and from `<linux/eventpoll.h>`.

I didn't find any straightforward solution yet, so I had to make an `.so` library file in C, that actually includes the header files mentioned above, and create exported functions that calls the actual linux calls, then I had to make a wrapper in C# around this `.so` library with marshaling/interopservices.

Even though it is working without any problem, I'd be happy if I could just skip using this `.so` library file, that actually works as a bridge between the C# runtime and Linux environment.

Is there any proper/more elegant way to call the Linux functions **from C#** without any bridging, since I just can not include the header files in C#?

Thank You for the answer in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile I figured out it is very simple, as all the needed syscalls are exported functions of the library `libc`, may be called via `DllImport`.

Socket functions may be accessed with:

```
    ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
    [DllImport("libc", EntryPoint = "socket", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern int socket(AddressFamily domain, SocketType type, ProtocolFamily protocol);

    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
    [DllImport("libc", EntryPoint = "bind", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern int bind(int socket, SockAddr *address, uint address_len);

    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
    [DllImport("libc", EntryPoint = "listen", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern int listen(int socket, int backlog);
```

etc...

And epoll functions may be accessed with:

```
    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
    [DllImport("libc", EntryPoint = "epoll_create", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern int epoll_create(int size);

    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
    [DllImport("libc", EntryPoint = "epoll_create1", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern int epoll_create1(int flags);

    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
    [DllImport("libc", EntryPoint = "epoll_ctl", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern int epoll_ctl(int epoll, int op, int fd, EpollEvent *epollevent);

    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
    [DllImport("libc", EntryPoint = "epoll_wait", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern int epoll_wait(int epoll, EpollEvent *epollevents, int maxevents, int timeout);
```

I've tested them and works under Debian with Mono, I'm sure they also would work with .Net Core.